# Adding a generic type to a function that returns impl Trait requires using the 'static lifetime

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have a function that takes references as parameters and returns `impl Future`. The future doesn't refer to the parameters (it takes a copy) so the references don't have to outlive the function call:

```
use futures::{Future, future}; // 0.1.25

pub struct Point<'a> {
    _name: &'a str,
}

pub fn write<'a>(_points: &'a [Point<'a>]) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static {
    future::ok(())
}

pub fn call_write(points: Vec<Point>) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
    // this works fine
    write(&points)
}
```

I'd like to adapt my `write` function to take a generic argument, but when I do this, the compiler thinks my function takes lifetime `'static` not `'a`:

```
pub fn write<'a, T: 'a>(_points: &'a [T]) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static {
    future::ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0621]: explicit lifetime required in the type of `points`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:42
   |
11 | pub fn call_write(points: Vec<Point>) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = ()> {
   |                           ----------     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'static` required
   |                           |
   |                           help: add explicit lifetime `'static` to the type of `points`: `std::vec::Vec<Point<'static>>`
```

My `write` function doesn't behave any differently with a generic `T` as with `Point`, so why does the compiler think the parameter to the generic `write` should be 'static?

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=731679e3c7101d7fde471849d6fad4fe)

The returned future does have lifetime `'static` as it doesn't hold references to the original parameters. In the real code, the parameters are serialised to a `Vec<u8>`, which is owned by the future.

Replacing `impl Future + 'static` with `Box<dyn Future + 'static>` works, so am I looking at a limitation of `impl Trait`?

```
pub fn write<'a, T: 'a>(_points: &'a [T]) -> Box<dyn Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + 'static> {
```

The error is the same before and after 1.30, so I think it must be something to do with impl Trait itself, rather than any recent change in lifetime elision. It seems to me that the return type is capturing lifetime bounds it shouldn't.

Comment: I suspect it might be an unintended consequence of the new lifetime elision rules for Rust 2018; can you try on an older compiler version (1.30 or earlier)?

Comment: Note that in Rust 2018 omitting lifetime parameters in non-reference types is deprecated, so you should write `Vec<Point<'_>>` instead of `Vec<Point>`.

Comment: @trentcl no it's the same on 1.30 and earlier. Must be a restriction in impl Trait itself, I'd like to learn exactly why though.